# Dj-rest-auth "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf, csrf-token, dj-rest-auth

When I am trying to post data using my dj-rest-auth api

http://localhost:8000/dj-rest-auth/login/

it gives this error CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing.

How do I fix this as I am unable to find the CSRF value to put into headers. Where can I actually find this value.

This is my settings for dj-rest-auth in views.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',

),
```

}

REST_AUTH = {

```
'USE_JWT': True,

'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'jwt-auth',
```

}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

```
# Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`

'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

# `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by email

'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
```

]

Tried sending a get request to this api but the method isn't allowed
Tried putting the csrf value of localhost:8000 in my headers which I got from mozilla firefox in the storage/cookies section. But it said the csrf value is incorrect.

Comment: Nvm I solved it by removing 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', from REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',

),
}